# New to programming, need slight assistance

Tags: java

So basically, my program compiles correctly and is working. However, when the program calculates the simple interest, it displays the incorrect value. Say it should be displaying $470, instead it is only printing out 4.7, sorry for the bad explanation, could anyone figure out why this is happening?

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
//import java.nio.file.*;
//import java.nio.file.Paths;
public class BankInterest {

  public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
  {

    /* TASK 1: Declare variables */

  Scanner user_input = new Scanner (System.in);

  boolean exit;
  int accountType;
    double balance;
    double principal;
  // double userInterest;
  double r;
  double r2;
  int year;

  String commBank = ("commbank.txt");
  String westPac = ("westpac.txt");

    /*Check if the expected command line is provided */

  if (args.length < 1) {
    /* Display the Usage */
    System.out.println("Usage: java BankInterest interestRateFileName");
    /* Programs quits with an error code */
    System.exit(-1);
 }

    /* TASK 2: Read interest rates from a file */

    String filename = (args[0]);
    Scanner textReader = new Scanner(new File(filename));
    r = textReader.nextDouble();
    r2 = textReader.nextDouble();
    System.out.println(r);
    System.out.println(r2);

    /* TASK 3: Take user input - Which Account */

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Which Account: ");
    System.out.println("1 - Savings");
    System.out.println("2 - Term Deposits");

    accountType = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (accountType == 1) {
      accountType = 1;
 }
    else if (accountType == 2) {
      accountType = 2;
 }

    /* TASK 4: Take user input - Principal and Period */

    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Principal: ");
    principal = keyboard.nextDouble();

    System.out.println("Years: ");
    year = keyboard.nextInt();

    /* TASK 5: Calculate balance for the chosen account type */

    if (accountType == 1) {
      double userBalance = principal * Math.pow((1 + r/100), year);
        double userInterest = userBalance-principal;
        System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("The Compound Interest is: " + userBalance);
    System.out.println("The total amount of Interest earned:" + userInterest);
  }
    else if (accountType == 2) {
      double userBalance = (principal * r2 * year) / 100;
        double userInterest = userBalance-principal;
     System.out.println("");
      System.out.println("The Simple Interest is: " + userBalance);
    System.out.println("The total amount of Interest earned:" + userInterest);

  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Use a debugger to see what's going on, or if you're not familiar with using a debugger (better learn it) you can also print out the values at different places to see if they are what you expect them to be.

Comment: Stop dividing by 100 maybe? I think we are going to need some more information, such as what your inputs are before we can help you out.

Comment: Printing the wrong number, does that happen with all of the numbers (compund interest, total interest, simple interest)? Does it seem to always print 1/100 of the number it should?

Comment: Consider posting an [MCVE]. Remove / replace all parts which are not essential to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: I took year to be the number of years the money was in the bank, not in percent. This goes to show that there still some explanation we’re missing.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly formula is wrong. The right one is (assuming that `r2` represents %):

```
double userInterest = (principal * r2 * year) / 100;
double userBalance = principal + userInterest;
```

Comment: The answer might be correct, but you need to explain why it is wrong, and post the correct one

Comment: Dude its the simple formula what should i explain S.I. = Principal * rate *time /100

Comment: @Ashish, I believe your formula is incorrect or at least not the one the OP wishes to use.

Comment: If interest is added once at the end, @Ashish’s formula is correct. If added once per year for more than one year, the basic idea in @Perfection’s original formula is correct. If added, say, 2 or 4 times per year, we need yet another formula.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it's just because you are giving the interest rate as percent. I mean for 20% interest rate the value in your file is 0.20. And in your calculation you divide it by 100 again. Either change your interest value to 20 or get rid of the division by 100 section in your calculation.